# Getting confidence intervals from an Xgboost fitted model

Tags: python, xgboost, confidence-interval

I am trying to get the confidence intervals from an XGBoost saved model in a .tar.gz file that is created using python XGBoost library.

The problem is that the model has already been fitted, and I dont have training data any more, I just have inference or serving data to predict. All the examples that I found entail using a training and test data to create either quantile regression models, or bagged models, but I dont think I have the chance to do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Why your desired approach will not work

I assume we are talking about regression here. Given a regression model that you cannot modify, I think you will not be able to achieve your desired result using only the given model. The model was trained to calculate a continuous value that appoximates some objective value (i.e., its true value) based on some given input. Nothing more.

### Possible solution

The only workaround I can think of would be to train *two more* models. These model's training goal would be to predict the **quality of the output of your given model**. One would calculate the upper bound of a given (i.e., predefined by you at training time) confidence interval and the other one the lower bound. This would probably include a lot of feature engineering. One would probably like to find features that correlate with the prediction quality of the *original* model.